# How to redraw Fragment within itself

Tags: android, fragment

I want to redraw a `Fragment` when my data for the `Fragment` gets updated, let's say in a `updateView()` method. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the FragmentManager and the FragmentTransaction class to dynamically switch fragments in & out of your UI. You do the following:

Define a container view for your fragments in XML. This can be a simple LinearLayout

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager . beginTransaction;
```

Add or remove fragments using

```
ft.add (R.id.frag_container, myFrag);
ft.replace (etc...)
ft.remover (etc...) 
ft.commit ();
```